# In-app purchase iOS: Transaction State .purchased is not called in sandbox environment

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am implementing IAP into my app. When I make a transaction in Sandbox environment, the transactionState .purchasing is called, then the app show me payment successfully like photo below. However, transactionState .purchased is not called. I was unable to handle complete the transaction.

Here is my code:

class IAPHelper: NSObject  {

```
// MARK: Variables
static let shared = IAPHelper()
private var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?
private var productsRequestCompletionHandler: ProductsRequestCompletionHandler?

// MARK: Initialization
private override init() {
    super.init()
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self) //for SKPaymentTransactionObserver
    clearPendingTransaction()
}

deinit {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
}

// MARK: Functionalities
// The reason to implement and call this method here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42790492/8120939
func clearPendingTransaction() {
    for transaction in SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
    }
}

func requestProducts(productIdentifiers: Set<ProductIdentifier>, _ completionHandler: @escaping ProductsRequestCompletionHandler) {
    productsRequest?.cancel()
    productsRequestCompletionHandler = completionHandler

    productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)
    productsRequest!.delegate = self
    productsRequest!.start()
}

public func buyProduct(_ product: SKProduct) {
    print("Buying \(product.productIdentifier)...")
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
}

public func canMakePayments() -> Bool {
    return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
}

static func restorePurchases() {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Singleton design pattern will be solved

Comment: Nhatduy's program's first line is "static let shared = IAPHelper()" , which is a Singleton pattern.

Answer (score -1):

I use `queue.finishTransaction(transaction)` in `.purchased`, `.restored` and `.failed` cases. Saving only in `.purchased` and .`restored`. I guess you need `break` only in `.purchasing` and `default` cases.

Comment: But my app does not call into .purchased and .restored